# directed acyclic graph: d-separation for conditional independence

Tags: bayesian-networks, graphical-model

[image]

If only X_1 was given, X_2 and X_3 would be conditionally independent since the "head" of the fork would be blocked. But for X_3, X_2 and X_4 we have a collider structure and the child of X_4 is observed which would make X_3 and X_2 conditionally dependent using d-separation. Does this now make X_3 and X_2 conditionally dependent even though X_1 is blocked?